# How can we create a custom input in react-admin v4 now that it uses `react-form-hook`?

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin v4.alpha.2 in order to test the latest features in our current app.

I cannot make our own custom input to work.

I read this great answer from @François Zaninotto, but this is for ra v3 using the "old" `react-final-form` and could not find something in the WIP documentation:
[Writing my own GeoJSON input component with a mapgox-gl interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245848/writing-my-own-geojson-input-component-with-a-mapgox-gl-interface)

There is no `useField` or `Field` in `react-hook-form`. Should we use `register` somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I spend time looking for solutions. Found it here...
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html
Section:Writing Your Own Input Component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).